# How to install xsane on ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, scanner, xsane

I recently know that there is software viz. SANE [Scanner Access Now Easy] which can automatically detect printer (almost all the printer) and one can easily scan via this software. So I search for that and find a page [sane community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane) and from this page, I get a command to install SANE. The command is

> sudo apt-get install sane sane-utils libsane-extras xsane

But while running this command in the terminal, it gives some errors and installation is not done.

The error message is shown in the picture.

Can anyone tell me how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing it directly from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your PC.

If the error persists then execute the command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*
```

Then try again.

What happens is that when ypu try installing a package/packages the package manager acquires the a lock on the database so that another instance of the package manager does not simultaneously perform operations.

Sometimes this process gets interrupted and the lock does not get released so you have to do it manually.

Comment: If you restart your pc all processes are bound to terminate. But if you are concerned try checking by using 'ps aux | grep apt'. If you find such a processes first kill it.